# Show all labels in line graph nvd3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

i work with nvd3.js to show line graph in a dashboard.  The problem is that cause the graph takes a small place, not all labels are showed for example : i want that all the days of the week are showed in the xaxis, but in my graph only monday, wednesday and Friday. When the graph takes all the width of the page all days are showed but i use the graph in a dashboard and it takes a small place.. i tried to use

```
 chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings

                  .axisLabelDistance(0)
```

but no results.
Any Help??

Comment: Please explain your problem better. The labels are getting clipped? You can just extend the margin.

Comment: Hello, no this is not the problem, the problem is that cause the graph takes a small place, not all labels are showed for example : i want that all the days of the week are showed in the xaxis, but in my graph only monday, wednesday and Friday. When the graph takes all the width of the page all days are showed but i use the graph in a dashboard and it takes a small place. Hope that it's clear and thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that better. Then I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show all labels in the line chart you have to set the tick values of the xAxis to be the same as the forceX numbers:

```
chart.xAxis.tickValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
```

These numbers above are representing the days of the week, replace them by the real values used for the days of the week.

If that does not solve the problem completely, you can force them on the chart too:

```
chart.forceX([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
```